# Excel sumif over non-contiguous range

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula

I have a set of paired columns of numbers, each associated with an adjacent tag field indicating if it belongs to a group or not (same flag for all). You could think of it as a row with various costs in it (values), and each is also tagged if taxable or not (tags).

Thus the data looks something like this in the sheet:

```
       A    B    C    D    E    F
      ---  ---  ---  ---  ---  --- 
 1:    n1  c1   n2   c2   n3   c3 ...
 2:    11       22    -   33 
 3:    12       22        34    -
```

I have a named range for each of these two sets of numbers; "values" is the name defining all columns with n's in them, and "tags" is the name defining all of the columns with the criteria. For the example above, in name-manager the definitions would look like this:

```
values=A:A,C:C,E:E   (and more)
tags=B:B,D:D,F:F
```

I can do a sum over the values, and it works fine, ( *=sum (1:1 values)* ) but I also want to do a sum over only the non-tagged values, and that seems harder. Conceptually I want to do something like this, for a total in each row of only the non-tagged values:

```
=SUMIF(1:1 tags, "", 1:1 values)
```

but it seems that *sumif* won't work over a named range with non-contiguous sections.
A *sumproduct* variation doesn't work either, it seems like for a similar reason;

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(1:1 tags=""),1:1 values)
```

How can I best do this?

(It would be nice if Excel would make explicit when a function is limited to only contiguous named regions.)

Comment: For *SUMIF* or any other formula to work, you need to meet not only the required arguments but other requirements. One requirement is the data lay-out. The way your data is laid out is not supported by any of the built in functions you're trying to use. If you could give another example with your expected result, creating a `UDF` may be possible.

Comment: Can you clarify precisely what the Named Ranges "values" and "tags" are? You use the plural when describing them: does this infer that you have created a single Named Range for each referring to a UNION of ranges? Or do you have multiple Named Ranges, e.g. "values1", "values2", "values3", etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Try this array formula:-

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:F3),A2:F3,0)*(LEFT(A1:F1,1)="n")*(B2:G3=""))
```

The trick is to put zeroes into the 2d array A2:F3 in the tag columns, then multiply the resulting array by the same array starting one place to the right, with the empty cells in the tag columns replaced with ones. So where the tag cells are blank, the corresponding value cells are multiplied by one and added to the total.

[image]

Comment: Very clever, thanks - but my problem was really an over simplification just to show that part of the problem, but it occurs in a broader context; these are defined as the dis-contigous ranges because they are not the only data in the rows, Again using the product-cost example, I have 6 sets of columns, and each is (product name, date of issue, cost, taxable-flag). Then I named all of the columns with cost together into the one name "values", and all of the taxable flags into "tags" name.  Again, thanks for the information and answer, and the "left" function, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you for positive feedback. I agree that if it's that complicated, you might have to end up just using sumif or sumifs within a group of columns and combining the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the `c1` on top of `n1` and avoid all this.

```
c1  c2  c3

n1  n2  n3

11  22  33
```

Is anything preventing you from doing that.

**On your comment**

You can leave the categories as is

I've Named the ranges A1:J1 as A and A2:J2 as B

Cell A1 contains formula =B2 and I will select A1:B1 as shown and copy to the end of range A (this would repeat the pattern of formula and empty cell)

This works. The only hard work you have to do for 100 or 1000 rows is copy the A1:B1 range to the end of your named range. (after copying these two cells you can go to end and ctrl+shift+left and then paste)

[image]

Comment: Nope - this would just transpose the problem into one with multiple rows needing to be combined. And there are ~100 rows.

Comment: Thanks - but I have ~100+ data rows like your A2, and if I understand your solution I would have to intersperse these with 100 versions of your Row-1, not practical, and it would ruin the actual data table which is used for other things as well. (the tags vary per row - they are not common to all values in a column.)